# How can I make custom rendered block readonly in Draft.js editor when its readOnly prop is true?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I'm using Draft.js `Editor` component. I have a custom block renderer specified correctly via `blockRendererFn` prop. The component renders the `EditorBlock` imported from draft-js as advised in the [Draft documentation](https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/docs/advanced-topics-block-components.html#content). In the props I get in my custom block renderer I don't have the information whether the block is readonly or not. At least not by default. I could get it via `blockProps`, however I feel I am missing something. Like it should work naturally when using the `EditorBlock`. Like it could get the `readOnly` value from context or something.

Is it my responsibility to render my block without the `EditorBlock` when `readOnly` is `true`? And id it my responsibility to propagate the `readOnly` value to my custom block renderer via `blockProps`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well I got this answered on the slack draftjs team so I'm going to sum it up here:

It should be enough to set `readOnly` to true to prevent any `onChange` callbacks in the entire editor. My problem was a kind of a bug, where I have set `editable` to `true` in the custom block renderer I have returned from the `blockRendererFn`. This caused the `readOnly` flag to be overridden and thus allowed for changes in my custom block. Isaac labeled this as potentially unwanted behavior.

The solution in my case was not to specify whether my block is editable or not on the custom block renderer. That way the `readOnly` is properly taken into account and there is nothing more I had to do.

Answer (score 4):

Passing readOnly={readOnly} to Editor fixes an issue.

```
<Editor
  readOnly={readOnly}
/>
```